# Access fields of an object in an array Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-arrayadapter

I am retrieving some data from Firebase, both name and id and I want to store that in an array and afterwards populate a spinner only with the name value.

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    People p = snapshot.getValue(People.class);
                    peopleArray.add(new String[]{p.name, String.valueOf(p.id)});
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, (List<String>) peopleArray);
                spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

In the ArrayAdapter I want to show only the names stored in peopleArray. How can I do that?

Comment: why are you adding string array instead just String peopleArray.add(p.name);

Comment: because I will need to access my id later on.

Comment: you can get id form dataSnapShot object when you click on spinner item.

Comment: the id that I defined in my data object ?

Comment: yes, absolutely

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: wait a min, I am writing your logic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this! I hope this helps you

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        People p = snapshot.getValue(People.class);

        //just adding id in list use later
        peopleArray.add(String.valueOf(p.id));

        //adding each name to your adapter
        dataAdapter.add(p.name);
    }


    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // get pID from peopleArray when item is selected 
            String pId = peopleArray.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: the id is always 0

Comment: add print statement in for loop, and check what are the ids your getting.

Comment: I had an error in my model class. This was a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
   List<People > people = new ArrayList<>();  
   List<String> peoplename = new ArrayList<>();       
   for(People people : people) {
        System.out.println(people.getName());
       // add name in separate list then assign to spinner.
       peoplename.add(people.getName());
    }
```

Set spinner

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, peoplename);
```